# using st_collect vs st_union to calculate centroids

Tags: postgis, st-union

Here is my code:

```
SELECT cluster_id, st_centroid(st_union(points_geom)) as cluster_centroid
FROM clustering 
GROUP by cluster_id
```

Should I replace st_union with st_collect? Because the coordinates for centroids I am getting with my current code do not match the expected results. This could be for a variety of reasons, but I want to see if my wrong usage of st_union could be a contributing factor.

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: Because the coordinates for centroids I am getting with my current code do not match the expected results.

Comment: Please add that to your question and include what results you expect. Only you know that and unless you ask specifically, you won't be able to get an answer that fits your problem ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ST_Collect` aggregates input sets into the minimally possible higher dimensional representation (either a `MULTI` geometry or a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`) **without changing the structure of the input geometries**. This is a comparably fast operation.

`ST_Union` is far more complex as it attempts to **remove overlaps and repeating vertices** from the geometric input structures - thus the output may be heavily altered, and the vertex count reduced significantly. This is a comparably costly operation.

Now, `ST_Centroid` calculates the *arithmetric mean* **of all vertices** of the input geometry; **any overlap** in an `ST_Collect`ion **adds bias to the arithmetic mean**, compared to its `ST_Union`.

Example:

```
WITH
  vals(geom) AS (
    VALUES
        -- geometries have overlaps - this is a possible result of ST_Collect
        ('SRID=4326;MULTIPOINT((0 0), (1 0), (1 0), (1 0), (2 0), (3 0), (4 0), (5 0))'),
        ('SRID=4326;MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 1 0, 2 0), (1 0, 2 0, 3 0, 4 0, 5 0))')
  )
SELECT
  ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(geom)) AS "ST_Collect",
  ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(ST_Union(geom))) AS "ST_Union"
FROM
  vals
GROUP BY
  geom
;


         ST_Collect         |   ST_Union   
----------------------------+--------------
 POINT(2.125 0)             | POINT(2.5 0)
 POINT(2.333333333333334 0) | POINT(2.5 0)
```

---

In other words, if you are certain to have no overlaps both functions will lead to the same `ST_Centroid` (and then `ST_Collect` is to be preferred for performance reason) - but for input geometries *with* overlaps, the `ST_Centroid` **will differ**!

Comment: I wouldn't say coincident points were "adding bias" - if you have 10 events at the same location and one event at another location, you probably want the centroid to be closer to the 10 events than the one event.

Comment: @Spacedman Hm, but I also said "*compared to its `ST_Union`*" - where then I think "bias" makes some sense, no?

Comment: I'm probably using "bias" in the statistical sense of a systematic error in an estimation, I guess its not likely to be misinterpreted here.

Answer (score 3):

`st_union` will merge coincident points, `st_collect` will preserve them. So a centroid computed with `st_collect` will give more weight to coincident points, with `st_union` any location with coincident points gets the same weight as a single point at that location.